# Extract SymmetricDS engine from war

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

I have `.war` file, generated from sample corp-000.properties deployed in Tomcat 8. Now I want to have a page with buttons to control this engine (namely, manually enable and disable synchronization, while keeping the engine and heartbeats running).

To do so I would like a way to extract a variable of a type `StandaloneSymmetricEngine` from this `.war` from another `servlet`. Is there any conceivable way to do so, or do I have something conceptually wrong in mind, and in that case, how should I resolve my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the JMX bean exposed for every SymmetricDS engine configured and it will allow full control.

Comment: I've never done anything with JMX. What should I do? Could you at least point me into the direction where I can read about it? (preferably, with examples)

Comment: Sure, more info on monitoring Tomcat 8 using its JMX: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand how that works now, but I'm still in the dark -- I'm trying to connect using `jconsole` to the address `localhost:31416` and it failes. Also, in the SymmetricDS userguide it says that SymmetricDS registeres itself in local processes as `SymmetricLauncher`, though it's not to be found in the processes list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Luckily SymmetricDs is an open source project. Check out the source of the  deployed version, import the project in your favorite IDE, enable Tomcat 8 remote debugging (http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/comment-page-1/), find the spot where SymmetricDs registers its JMX and try to realize what's going on from there.

Comment: When started as standalone, `HTTP Adaptor` works and `JConsole` sees and connects to SymmetricDS as a local application. Yet, I need to connect to it using url from java code (if I understand correctly, how MBeans work) -- and that does not work. I've looked into source code, and in the file: `symmetric-server\src\main\java\org\jumpmind\symmetric\SymmetricWebServer.java` I've found only three properties extracted from file, and judging by default values, they are `jmx.http.port`, `https.port` and `http.port`, yet there is no extraction of `jmx.agent.port` which I think is needed for `JConsole`

Comment: It's better to pose a new question tagged with tomcat8 and jmx